# Json post with android

Tags: android, json, gson

I'm reading directly json, but now "post" challenge by the need to read.

[example code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMJvj.png)

Comment: I recommend to read [ask] a question.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Ahlem Jarrar   json data sent and read. but to make the following structure

Comment: Still don't know what the question is...